# Short story about a man in a parking garage driving faster every floor he goes up

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for short science fiction story I read in the early 1980s in an 8th grade literature text book.  It's about a man going up floor by floor in a parking garage looking for a parking spot.  He keeps going up and tries in increase his speed every time he goes up another floor.  At the end he comes out on a huge freeway or race track, avoids a crash with another car and then starts going back down.  It was highly surreal.

Comment: Is there anything fantasy or sci-fi about this story?

Comment: @SeanDuggan I'm sure it's a drift racers fantasy to find a race track at the top of a parking garage. Though I think Fast and the Furious already did this.

Comment: @SeanDuggan It certainly sounds fantastic to me.

Comment: @Firebat Reminds me of [the old Fiat factory](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Fiat_Lingotto_veduta-1928.jpg), as seen in *The Italian Job*.

Answer (score 3):

What you read was an excerpt from "The Parking Tower" in the book *[Gasoline: the Automotive Adventures of Charlie Bates](https://books.google.com/books?id=KACxAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Parking%20)* By James D. Houston.

The plot is identical, Charlie Bates is trying to park and keeps driving upward as he looks for an empty space.

Comment: What are the points where this story matches the op's story?

Comment: The plot is identical, Charlie Bates is trying to park and keeps driving upward as he looks for an empty space. The excerpt was included in an 80s anthology of literature that I also read in school. 

https://books.google.com/books?id=KACxAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Parking+

Comment: Edit the answer to include the points where they match and you'll improve the answer and earn reputation when folks upvote your answer.